# Max-width:100% for images in Mozilla doesn't work in a div

Tags: css, firefox

I have a problem with images in Mozilla.
I've read a lot of similar topics but nothing works and all of them were concerned with an image in a table-cell or in a floated div.
However, my images are in a simple div which is not floated. In Mozilla images have always the width 100% of the cantaining div, despite of max-width:100%;

My code for Mozilla images:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
section.front img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    }
}
```

An image comparing images in Mozilla and Chrome (in Chrome everything's fine):
http://oi65.tinypic.com/11ijq7p.jpg

Comment: can't understand your problem. Can you please elaborate or share an image that will display the exact problem?

Comment: I don't see the differences... Where you've the problem? http://prntscr.com/a6u67f

Comment: I've edited my question and added an image of my problem: http://oi65.tinypic.com/11ijq7p.jpg
The image is simply too  wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use firefox inspector, you can try this script in your css file on line: 403:

```
section.front img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Cannot believe that! I wouldn't have thought of making height:100% and width simply auto. Thank you!